# Keras & TensorFlow: getting 2nd derivative of f(x) wrt x, where dim(x) = (1, n)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, derivative, hessian-matrix

I'm working in Keras with TensorFlow under the hood. I have a deep neural model (predictive autoencoder). I'm doing something somewhat similar to this: https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.00796 -- I'm trying to understand influence of variables in a given layer on the output.

For this I need to find 2nd derivative (Hessian) of the loss (L) with respect to output of particular layer (s): [image]

Diagonal entries would be sufficient. L is a scalar, s is 1 by n.

What I tried first:

```
dLds = tf.gradients(L, s)  # works fine to get first order derivatives
d2Lds2 = tf.gradients(dLds, s)  # throws an error
TypeError: Second-order gradient for while loops not supported.
```

I also tried:

```
d2Lds2 = tf.hessians(L, s)
ValueError: Computing hessians is currently only supported for one-dimensional tensors. Element number 0 of `xs` has 2 dimensions.
```

I cannot change shape of s cause it's a part of neural network (LSTM's state). The first dimension (batch_size) is already set to 1, I don't think I can get rid of it.

I cannot reshape s because it breaks flow of the gradients, e.g.:

```
tf.gradients(L, tf.reduce_sum(s, axis=0))
```

gives:

```
[None]
```

Any ideas on what can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported at the moment. See [this report](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15219).